# Add row to table and send to server, post table via jquery to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html-table

I'm trying to make a table where I can add a new row with a button click and then send the table to the server so it remembers the information on page refresh. Below is a button which successfully adds a row to a table with the current time. However, when I send the table to the server via the "Send to Server" button it does not echo back the updated table, only the original. It would be such a relief to get this figured out.

HTML:

```
<input type = "button" id = "send" value = "Send to Server" />
<input type = "button" id = "add" value = "Add Row" />
<table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <td><h2>In</h2></td>
            <td><h2>Out</h2></td>
            <td><h2>Total</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>InData</td>
            <td>OutData</td>
            <td>TotalData</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$("#add").click(function(){

    var dt = new Date();
    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds(); //set variable to current time
    $('table > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>'+time+'</td><td></td><td></td></tr>'); //add row to table with current time

});

$(function(){
    var dataArr = [];
    $("table").each(function(){
        dataArr.push($(this).html());
    });
    $('#send').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url : 'timesheet.php',
          data : "content="+dataArr,
          success: function(data) {
              alert(data);// alert the data from the server
          },
          error : function() {
          }
         });
    });
});
</script
```

PHP (timesheet.php):

```
<?php 
    echo $_REQUEST['content'];
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't sending the data? Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: Yeah, you're gonna need to save that information to a database in order for PHP to know it's there and make use of it.  You can't rely on posting data to PHP and expect it to remember it.

Comment: I haven't written in the code to send it to a database yet. All I want to do now is echo back the updated table but it only returns the original one. It definitely sends it to the php file and returns it in an alert box but what shows up in the alert is the original table, not the one with the added row.

Comment: I can see in the inspector window that the html is changing when I add a row so why doesn't it send this current code to the php file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I send the table to the server via the "Send to Server" button it does not echo back the updated table, only the original.

**Solution**

Use `.on()` instead of `.click()`

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).on('click', '#add', function(){

    var dt = new Date();
    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds(); //set variable to current time
    $('table > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>'+time+'</td><td></td><td></td></tr>'); //add row to table with current time

});

$(document).on('click', '#send', function(){
    var dataArr = [];
    $("table").each(function(){
        dataArr.push($(this).html());
    });
    $('#send').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url : 'timesheet.php',
          data : "content="+dataArr,
          success: function(data) {
              alert(data);// alert the data from the server
          },
          error : function() {
          }
         });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Edited:**

The `click()` binding you're using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach the handler to elements that *already exist*. It won't get bound to elements created in the future. To do that, you'll have to create a "delegated" binding by using `on()`.

From the [documentation of `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

Comment: You're welcome! :)
See the **edited** section of my answer.