# Inserting different form elements in mysql trough jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, forms

I can't seem to figure this one out, nor how to start my query.
I have a form with different input field ID's
(customer_relationid, customer_brand, customer_goal, customer_floors, ....)
I have a mysql table with 3 columns (auto increment id, Key, Value)
The goal is to post all the info from the form row by row in mysql so that it results in this :
**column id**
this is just a auto increment, not important in this case

**column KEY**
relationid
brand
goal
floors
....

**column VALUE**
15
sony
music
3
.....

This is part of my form (the rest of the fields is the same):

```
<form id="calculator_form"> 
<fieldset id="generalInfo">
    <legend>General Info</legend>
    <h2>General Info</h2>
    <label for="calculator_relationID">relationID:</label>                          
    <input type="text" name="calculator_relationID" style="width:250px;" id="calculator_relationID" class="calculator_relationID">
    <label for="calculator_brand">Brand:</label>                            
    <input type="text" name="calculator_brand" style="width:250px;" id="calculator_brand" class="calculator_brand">
    <label for="calculator_goal">Goal:</label>                          
    <input type="text" name="calculator_goal" style="width:250px;" id="calculator_goal" class="calculator_goal">
    <label for="calculator_floors">Floors:</label>                          
    <input type="text" name="calculator_floors" style="width:250px;" id="calculator_floors" class="calculator_floors">
    ...                     
</fieldset>
```

How can I create the query as such so it knows it needs to insert it row by row for each form element?

Tnx in advance!

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: that's a bit difficult, because i'm still in the "think it over phase"... like in.. i'm staring at a blank page.. I have the static form output in a querystring.. and that's where it ends :(

Comment: I understand. Can you please show your form HTML code?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833780/add-row-to-table-and-send-to-server-post-table-via-jquery-to-php

Comment: I looked at examples like this, but they are all talking about adding rows with the same id, except a different number. Mine has differect keys (floors, brand, goal,...) so no numbers like customer_1, customer_2, ... the part after calculator_ is the part that needs to go in column KEY, and the data from the input needs to go into VALUE